# I removed my double sink's drain pipe and now I can't get it back on properly

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

Pipe had been clogging regularly ever since we had it installed, opening and poking around the cleanout tap stopped improving the situation.it was filled with tons of sludge and fat residues I removed and cleaned the whole thing.

Now I can't get it to fit back properly. Am I missing something all the tutorial videos and pics I checked mention a tailpiece which I don't have. There is no way for the joint nut to hold together the end of the pipe and the strainer's end together. Was it just jammed in there? [image]

Comment: It was either forced into place or one or more of the fittings by your hand was moved.  Try loosening the nuts by your hand(in the picture) and see if pipes line up better.

Comment: You've forgotten to re-install that piece lying on the ground. It goes on the piece of pipe on the left and will make it look just like the piece on the right, giving you a slip-joint nut and washer to tighten up on both sides.

Comment: First, as noted, there is a piece on the floor. Is that the one you're missing?  Second, why is there a big floor pan beneath this?   If it is all leaking on a regular basis I suggest you entirely replace it, including the bits attached to the sink.  What country are you in?   In the US you can replace everything in the picture for about $30 and less than 2 hours work.  A pro could do it in half an hour easily.  It should not require a drip pan.  The replacement will be simpler with fewer parts.

Comment: That's the joint nut I can't get to hold the pipe and strainer together, the are both the same size, even if I turn the joint nut just once the pipe falls off, i think not the pipes were glued in place using silicone.                                    The pan is there for whenever we opened the cleanout tap which was at least once a week

Comment: I don't see any threading on the left hand sink drain.  Maybe it's just the lighting, maybe there is thread there.  Maybe it's stripped or damaged.   I'll assume you're right, ie it was glued or whatever, and I'll Answer suggesting total replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If the parts don't fit together and by the looks of the drip pan they are all leaking anyway, just replace everything!

Two of these $11 each

[image]

One of these $7

[image]

One of these $4

[image]

In the end it looks like this (this picture also has a dishwasher connection point)
[image]

Comment: Thx a lot, I kinda managed to put it back Turned the pipes around and it worked but it also turns out that the center piece was the one that was insulated with silicone so now it's leaking